# Postgres: Convert Object Graphs to JSON

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

Is there a procedure that converts Postgres Object Graphs to a nested JSON tree?

**Context:**

- An author has many books.
- A book has many review.

The query below gets all reviews of all books of all authors:

```
select author.id, book.title, review.text
from author
left join book on author.id = book.author_id
left join review on book.id = review.book_id;
```

With my test data set, this returns:

```
id  title                       text
1   Oathbringer                 obath
1   Oathbringer                 oath
1   The Way of Kings            a
1   The Way of Kings            bye
1   The Way of Kings            hi
2   The Eye of the World        w
3   The Fellowship of the Ring  x
```

The tabular format is inconvenient, so I convert it to json:

```
select json_agg(sub2.*) as data from (
  select sub.id, sub.title, json_agg(sub.text) as review from (
    select author.id, book.title, review.text
    from author
    left join book on author.id = book.author_id
    left join review on book.id = review.book_id
  ) as sub group by sub.id, sub.title
) as sub2;
```

The data is fetched as

```
[  
   {  
      "id":1,
      "title":"Oathbringer",
      "review":[  
         "obath",
         "oath"
      ]
   },
   {  
      "id":1,
      "title":"The Way of Kings",
      "review":[  
         "a",
         "bye",
         "hi"
      ]
   },
   {  
      "id":2,
      "title":"The Eye of the World",
      "review":[  
         "w"
      ]
   },
   {  
      "id":3,
      "title":"The Fellowship of the Ring",
      "review":[  
         "x"
      ]
   }
]
```

Unfortunately, the query is not correct because books for an author are not getting aggregated. Attempting to correct this, I wrote this query:

```
select sub2.id, json_agg((sub2.title, sub2.review)) as data from (
  select sub.id, sub.title, json_agg(sub.text) as review from (
    select author.id, book.title, review.text
    from author
    left join book on author.id = book.author_id
    left join review on book.id = review.book_id
  ) as sub group by sub.id, sub.title
) as sub2 group by sub2.id;
```

But the json keys are messed up ('f1' instead of 'title', 'f2' instead of 'review').

**Questions:**

- How would the correct query be written?
- Can you modify `json_agg(sub2.*)` to explicitly list the columns to aggregate? The most obvious way, e.g.`json_agg((sub2.title, sub2.review))` creates json objects with nonsensical keys 'f1', 'f2', etc.
- Is there a better way to convert object graphs to JSON? Correctly nesting queries, and grouping and aggregating fields is tricky to get right. How would you write a program that generates a SQL query returning JSON given an object graph?